# extract word from string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I need to extract part of a string in sql server. Lets say I have this string in a column...

```
Name1=Bill Gates&Name2=Microsoft&Address1=The streetadress
```

How can I extract the text that is equal to Name2 eg Microsoft?

Comment: Is the Name1, Name2, Address1 is fixed for all values in different rows?

Comment: Yes they are fixed...

Comment: My two cents: If the OP had shown effort, this question would merit not being closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One old fashioned way of handling this is to just use basic string functions like `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(col,
              CHARINDEX('Name2', col) + 6,
              CHARINDEX('&', col, CHARINDEX('Name2', col)) -
                  CHARINDEX('Name2', col) - 6) AS name
FROM yourTable
```

Note that this solution assumes that the key value pairs are fixed in the order you showed us.  My query uses the ambersand after the second name as a termination marker.  If this be not present, e.g. if `Name2` could possibly the *last* key in the string, then my query would have to be updated.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @string varchar(100) = 'Name1=Bill Gates&Name2=Microsoft&Address1=The streetadress'


select replace(PARSENAME (replace(@string, '&', '.'), 2), 'Name2=', '');
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for great help!

Comment: I love this idea of using a function PARSENAME designed to parse names of SQL objects for parsing out words from a string.  Great lateral thinking and simple :)

Comment: Just be aware that it reads string chunks from right to left.  If the string would have a varying number of chunks then this might cause a problem